# Have any systems incorporated Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Tags: product-identification

I'm curious if there are any official or unofficial RPGs based around the world of [Avatar: The Last Airbender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar%3a_The_Last_Airbender).

Comment: The first part of this question is perfectly fine- "Are there RPGs based on Avatar?" That has an answer (yes or no) and probably suggests a specific system or systems. The second part is a lot more iffy- lots of systems could do this maybe do this. I'd constrain the second part by whatever the OP thinks is the important part of this universe. So far we have "different martial arts, elemental powers, weird creatures." We need more to go on.

Comment: If you want to ask about best fit, please review the game recommendation question rules linked in the tag wiki on Meta.

Comment: I am pretty sure someone has reskinned DnD 3.5 into Avatar world but can't find a link. I am sure I had the link from this SE though. I'll try to find it later today if no one posts it in the meantime.

Comment: @mxyzplk Is this still a game recommendation question, technically speaking? I'm not sure, since it's not asking for a recommendation any longer... at least not in the same sense as most of our game-rec questions

Comment: No.  The question as scoped is identification only.  Please restrict your answers to conversions and the like, not your favorite supers game.

Comment: As it stands now, there are 4 answers to this, all of which answer the question correctly, but each offers it's own alternative. I feel that there is no way to pick an objectively correct answer. I have therefore consolidated them into a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: this is a community wiki entry consolidating the existing answers, none of which is can objectively be designated as "best", or "correct".

---

There are no official Avatar The Last Airbender RPGs.

There are several unofficial ones though.

- [Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple](http://www.evilhat.com/home/do-pilgrims-of-the-flying-temple/) was influenced by it, though more in the "kids explore magical world and get into hijinks" aspect, not so much in the serious themes or the martial arts side.
- The [Avatar d20](https://sites.google.com/site/avatard20/) project is a set of homebrew classes, prestige classes, feats and monsters for use with D&D 3.5. To quote their website:

  > The Avatar d20 setting is intended to be used with the d20 fantasy roleplaying rules system, and is designed with the intent that much of the existing content will be usable.  It presents four new base classes as well as a few new monsters that appear in the Avatar world.  The setting is currently incomplete, and new content will (hopefully) be added at a later date.
- There is a [Avatar TLA conversion for Savage Worlds](http://savagepedia.wikispaces.com/Avatar+the+Last+Airbender) on the Savagepedia. Savage worlds is pretty adaptable out of the box, so this conversion doesn't actually have to add much. It adds bending as an Arcane Background, with the specific moves done via powers, and also suggests some trappings (fluff and minor crunch changes) based on the bending disciplines, including metal and lightning (which have corresponding Edges to unlock them first).
- If you go over to the [Atomic Think Tank](http://www.atomicthinktank.com/) you'll find several people have adapted the game to the setting.  As M&M is a superpowers game- and very adaptable- is is really easy to do.  For the most part, keep the power level low (between 6 to 8) for normal benders, and put all elemental bending powers into a "container" (2e term; closest thing is an static power array, or perhaps just a way to organize the powers on a character sheet).

Answer (score 6):

There is [Avatar d20 project](https://sites.google.com/site/avatard20/) about which I can't really say much except quote its own page:

> The Avatar d20 setting is intended to be used with the d20 fantasy roleplaying rules system, and is designed with the intent that much of the existing content will be usable.  It presents four new base classes as well as a few new monsters that appear in the Avatar world.  The setting is currently incomplete, and new content will (hopefully) be added at a later date.

Answer (score 5):

There are no official Avatar The Last Airbender rpgs.

[Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple](http://www.evilhat.com/home/do-pilgrims-of-the-flying-temple/) was influenced by it, though more in the "kids explore magical world and get into hijinks" aspect, not so much in the serious themes or the martial arts side.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a [Savage Worlds Conversion](http://savagepedia.wikispaces.com/Avatar+the+Last+Airbender) based on TLA on the Savagepedia.

Savage worlds is pretty adaptable out of the box, so this conversion doesn't actually have to add much. It adds bending as an Arcane Background, with the specific moves done via powers, and also suggests some trappings (fluff and minor crunch changes) based on the bending disciplines, including metal and lightning (which have corresponding Edges to unlock them first).

Answer (score 4):

If you go over to the [Atomic Think Tank](http://www.atomicthinktank.com/) you'll find several people have adapted the game to the setting.  As M&M is a superpowers game- and very adaptable- is is really easy to do.  For the most part, keep the power level low (between 6 to 8) for normal benders, and put all elemental bending powers into a "container" (2e term; closest thing is an static power array, or perhaps just a way to organize the powers on a character sheet).

Answer (score 1):

[Aspect](http://stonetabletgames.com/aspect.html) does a great job of encompassing the bending and non-bending aspects of most of what characters do in Avatar. Some of the rarer stuff like blood bending can be accounted for with pacts and stuff. It also has a bunch of Arcane, Supernatural, and Divine stuff that you could just rule is not available in your game world.

Comment: You should throw this in the Community Wiki Answer at the top of the answers.

Answer (score -3):

I wrote the bulk of one way back in '09:
http://www.tgdmb.com/viewtopic.php?t=50257

...huh, keeps getting flagged as spam. Maybe if I type some more words in here it will let me share this